# Resetting Action type with AJAX Resource Maintenance

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I have developed a Rails 3 program that maintains a resource ie. it Creates, Updates, Lists and Deletes records without screen refresh requests. It uses AJAX requests to communicate with the server. Each request is processed by the controller and then a js.erb file with JavaScript code to update the DOM is transmitted from the server for execution by the Browser. From the user perspective the program works as follows :

The top part of the screen consists of an input form, used to insert and edit/ update a resource record. The bottom part of the screen lists out all resource records with actions for edit and destroy at the end of each record line.

All actions, when executed individually work correctly, in that the action ( create, edit/update, destroy ) takes place and the resource list is updated on screen without a screen refresh request.

The problem is that at the end of an edit/update action set, the action type on screen gets "stuck" in update mode and i can't switch to create mode again.

Similarly, when I execute the destroy action the screen action remains at "create" or "update" - depending on the previous action executed.

In both edit/update and destroy cases I want to set the next action to create mode.

Any thoughts on how I can solve this problem.

I have tried to use the JQuery attr() function to set the next action without any success.

Some parts of the code are shown below.

```
Controller code :

class CustomersController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :load

  def load
    @customers = Customer.all
    @customer  = Customer.new
  end

  # Display composite form used for AJAX operations.

  def index   
  end




  # This method implements customer create action for AJAX request.

  def create  
    @customer = Customer.new(params[:customer])
    if @customer.save
      flash[:notice] = "Customer Record Created."
      @customers = Customer.all
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end 

  end 


  # This method get customer for editing using AJAX.

  def edit
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])   
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  # This method implements customer update from AJAX form.

  def update
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    if @customer.update_attributes(params[:customer])
      flash[:notice] = "Customer Record Updated."
      @customers = Customer.all
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end 
    end
  end  

  # This method implements customer delete from AJAX form.

  def destroy
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    @customer.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Customer Record Deleted"
    @customers = Customer.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end

  end

  # This method lists all customers on file. 

  def getcustsjson
    render :json => @customers
  end

  # This method lists all the books purchased by a particular customer.

  def getbooksjson

    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id]) 
    @order = @customer.order
    @orderitems = Orderitem.find_all_by_order_id(@order)
    @book = Book.find_all_by_id(@orderitems)

    render :json => @book 

  end 

end

edit.js.erb file:

editform = "";
editform = editform + '<%= escape_javascript( render('form') ) %>';
alert(" unEscaped editform : " + editform);
$("#customer_form").html(editform);



Update.js.erb file:




 <% if @customer.errors.any? -%> 

   /* Hide the Flash Notice div */
   /* Create an Errors List */
   /* Update the html of the customer_errors div with the Errors List */
   /* Show the customer_errors div */

   $("#flash_notice").hide(300);

   var errlst = "";
   errlst = errlst + "<ul>";
   <% @customer.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
     errlst = errlst + "<li><%= escape_javascript(msg) %></li>";
   <% end %>
   errlst = errlst + "</ul>";

   alert("Errors List : " + errlst);

   $("#customer_errors").html(errlst);
   $("#customer_errors").show(300);

<% else -%>

   /* Hide the customer_errors div */
   /* Update the html of the flash_notice div with the Flash contents */
   /* Clear the form */
   /* Set form for Create Customer mode */
   /* Replace the html of the customers_list div with the updated Customers List */

   $("#customer_errors").hide(300);
   $("#flash_notice").html("<%= flash[:notice] %>");

   $(":input:not(input[type=submit])").val("");
   $(":submit").attr("value", "Create Customer");
   $("form").attr({id:"new_customer", action:"/customers"});

   $("#customers_list").html("<%= escape_javascript render('customers') %>");

<% end %>



Index.html file:


<div id="customer_form"><%= render 'form' %></div>
<div id="customers_list"><%= render 'customers' %></div>


_form.html partial :


<%= form_for(@customer, :remote => true ) do |f| %>

  <div id="customer_errors" style="display:none"></div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :firstname %>
    <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
    <%= f.label :lastname %>
    <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
    <%= f.label :phone %>
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.text_field :password %>
    <%= f.label :address_id %>
    <%= f.text_field :address_id %>
  </div>

  <div id="next_action", class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>



_customers.html partial :


<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th>Password</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= customer.firstname %></td>
    <td><%= customer.lastname %></td>
    <td><%= customer.email %></td>
    <td><%= customer.phone %></td>
    <td><%= customer.password %></td>
    <td><%= customer.address_id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_customer_path(customer), :remote => true %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', customer, :remote => true, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

EDIT :  Problem solved using attr() function in JQuery - see code for update.js.erb above. Final piece was to use the ":submit" element to reset the submit button value to Create Customer. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Could you post some come code so one could help with diagnosing the problem?
What you describe here sounds an awful lot like a scoping problem but without code it could be anything

Comment: Tigraine - pasted in some code, including my attempts to use attr() function in update.js.erb file

Comment: This code looks fine actually.. but it's rather complicated to follow. Where do you actually do the AJAX request and process the returned JavaScript?

Comment: The AJAX request is generated by rails using the :remote => true construct in the partials _form and _customers. The .js.erb files are executed by the Browser after being sent by Rails. The main function of the .js files is to update the DOM put in place initially by the index.html file sent by rails to the browser.

Comment: Do you get all of the alerts you sprinkled in there? I would suggest using `console.log()` to not interrupt execution flow while still seeing debug info..

Comment: Yes, I do. Just comment them out when I've finished with them.Did you have a look at the attr() statements - I know the first two are wrong in that all they do is set up two new attributes at the div level. Tigraine.

Comment: I really can't see what is wrong with your `.attr()` usage. Even after looking at the ujs driver at https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js - simply setting the `action` attribute should generate the correct calls to the server. 
Maybe you should inspect the generated DOM to check wether or not there are two forms nested into each other by accident..

Comment: Got mode working - now only need to change the value attribute for submit button on screen from Update Customer to Create Customer. My code in update.js.erb changes the attribute internally to Create Customer", but the screen still remains at "Update Customer". Any ideas Tigraine.

Comment: Fixed - used $(":submit").attr function to change value to Create Customer - worked fine. See update.js.erb code. Thanks for your help Tigraine - much appreciated.